# How to animate a Drawable in Android?

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a `Drawable` object in my application which is moving on the screen:

```
public class MyDrawable extends Drawable {

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

It worked fine so far but now I have to animate this `Drawable`. I checked out the documentation and it looks like that the best option for me is using `AnimationDrawable`.

I did something like this:

```
public void addAnimation() {
    animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    animation.addFrame(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.anim_0), 100);
    animation.addFrame(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.anim_1), 100);
    animation.addFrame(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.anim_2), 100);
    animation.addFrame(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.anim_3), 100);
    animation.setOneShot(false);
    refreshAnimationBounds();
    animation.start();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    refreshAnimationBounds();
    animation.draw(canvas);
}
```

What happens is that my original `Drawable` is moving as intended but I only see the first frame. What could be the problem?

`refreshAnimationBounds();` is just refreshing the bounds of my `Drawable` object (repositions it).

Edit:

The common:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        animation.start();
    } else {   
        animation.stop();
    }
}
```

solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In general Animation package is quite buggy. I recall I had same problem with animation not starting and the solution I came with was to start it not in `onCreate()` as I formerly did but `onWindowFocusChanged()` once all view stuff was set. I wasn't extending AnimationDrawable myself but it may be the same origin in your case.

Comment: there is no such method. I'm not using `Animation` but `AnimationDrawable` which is a different thing.

Comment: As I already told you **there is no `setRepeatCount`** method to call. using `onWindowFocusChanged` doesn't help either. I'm not extending `AnimationDrawable` but putting one in my `Drawable`.

Comment: @AdamArold, have you fount solution?